# Finding a node with a time closest to the current time without being past

Tags: views

I am working on a site which has a Class (ECK) entity type. Each Class may have 0+ "Class Offerings," which are instances of a class at a specific date. I am trying to create a view listing a class and the next upcoming Offering for each class (if one exists). If there is no upcoming Offering, I would still like to list the Class. How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely!

Add a filter to your view, that is based on your date field and choose the operator as 'Is greater than or equal to'.

You have as an option to enter a relative date for the comparison and then enter in any variety of relative times and dates.  For your purpose just choose 'now' as the comparison.

That will pull up all nodes with a date field that is greater than or equal to now: i.e. all the future ones!

[image]

============= EDIT ===============

If you don't need all of the future ones, just limit the results to 1 and order by the date.  That will give you just the *next* one coming up.

Let us know if that works for you!

Comment: Sorry, that is not quite what I need. I want the equivalent of a "Representative Node" relationship to display the closest future one, but not any more.

Comment: Got it - edited my answer above - just sort by date and have views return a single node.  That will give you just the *next* one coming up based on the current time.  Makes sense?

Comment: I'm *really* sorry, but that is still a bit off. The entities with the dates have references to another entity type, which is what I am listing; I want to display the next one coming up for **each** entity.